# Issues trying to make a filter using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make my software filter a list of elements.
I think I need to put my data in a TableWidget because I have to display other information.

I also put 3 Line Edit to search respectively in each category (called leName, leSource, leDestination)

so I tried to implement my filter for the name property, for now I have :

```
void MyClass::on_leName_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{
   for (int i=0;ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1;i++)
   {
       qDebug()<<"before if";
       if(ui->tableWidget->item(0,1)->text().contains(arg1) //tried with &arg1, I have the same issue, for now
       {
            qDebug()<<"If validated";
            ui->tableWidget->showRow(i);
       }else{
            qDebug()<<"If not validated"
            ui->tableWidget->hideRow(i)
       }
   }
}
```

When I hit a key, my soft crashes
I get "Before if", "If (not) validated", "Before if" from qDebug

I launched with debbugger and got Segmentation fault as error
not sure what I could add as detail about my error

Maybe I did nothing in the good way, I'm no expert in Qt nor c++

If you have any idea of what I should do to correct this, I would appreciate it =)

Comment: Create a model for your data and use QSortFilterProxyModel with a QTableView.

Comment: Ok I'm looking into this =) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that a cell exists does not imply that it has an associated QTableWidgetItem, so you must verify that it is not null.

```
QTableWidgetItem * item = ui->tableWidget->item(0, 1);
if(item && item->text().contains(arg1))
{
    qDebug() << "If validated";
    ui->tableWidget->showRow(i);
}else{
    qDebug() << "If not validated"
    ui->tableWidget->hideRow(i)
}
```